# is there a way to render a form when a button is pressed ? PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am looking for some help in core PHP. I want to know how to display a form in a window when a button is pressed. It should be like the conditional rendering in react or svelte etc. I don't want to use any framework any laravel.

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button and have that other page open via an url like this

```
<button type="button" onclick='"location.href="someurl.php?someparams"'>Some button</button>
```

Where the single quote enclosure on the `onclick` means the double quotes get sourced correctly. The "type" on button as *button* is so if this were enclosed in a form, the form will not confuse it with *submit* behavior.

Hopes this helps.